# Trouble on installing pods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to install this pod '*YBTextPicker*' through the my Cocoapods Podfile instead of dragging and dropping the project into Xcode. However, I got the following error after running `pod install` command:

> **[!] Unable to find a specification for 'YBTextPicker'.**

What am I doing wrong? This is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'ViewLib' do
    pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', '~> 1.3.1'
    pod 'BEMCheckBox'
    pod 'EPSignature', :git => 'https://github.com/MC1Tecnologia/EPSignature.git'
    pod 'YBTextPicker', :git => 'https://github.com/YahyaBagia/YBTextPicker.git'
    pod 'Charts', '~> 3.1.1'
end
```

[Here is the framework URL](https://github.com/YahyaBagia/YBTextPicker) if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `YBTextPicker` doesn't exists as a pod. You can't just add any git project to your `podfile`; they need to have a `podspec` (and, if you want to install them without specifying a git path, their podspec needs to be added to the [master Cocoapods repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs).)

You can fork the branch and create your own pod. But that is a bit of work.

https://cocoapods.org/

Comment: It's not too hard. You just need to add a podspec which, among other things, tells Cocoapods where in the repo to find the source files / resources it needs. Look for examples on other existing Cocoapods / on the Cocoapods website to figure out how to make a podspec and as u.gen mentions, you can fork the repository and add your podspec to your fork. Make sure to use your fork as the git path.